# Django: absolute URI in batch/cron job

Tags: django, url, cron-task

How can you get the absolute uri (with domain and scheme (http/https)) from a batch/cron job?

The method [build_absolute_uri()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri) needs an HttpRequest, which I don't have in a cron job.

Answer (score 2):

Two examples:

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

url = 'http://' + Site.objects.get_current().domain + my_obj.get_absolute_url()
```

or

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

url = 'http://' + Site.objects.get_current().domain + reverse('my_view')
```